# Survey Creation in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, survey-list, survey

I am trying to create a more visually appealing SharePoint survey. I have created the survey in SharePoint already and I have tried editing it in SharePoint designer, but have had no luck. I really just need to fix the spacing in a few areas between questions. Is it possible to pull the survey HTML into SharePoint Designer and then just fix the spacing and stuff there? Or is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: you can use info path if you have access on it

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the Html in Designer if you need to change the html structure. Otherwise you could make CSS adjustments and add reference to the page using Designer.